# Making a container responsive in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following code, that I am looking to make responsive for mobile display:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Retrieve</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="container" style="min-height: 530px !important;margin-top: 5%;">
  <div class="form-container log-in-container" style="    background: white;">

    Hellow world
  </div>
  <div class="overlay-container" style="background-image:url('/assets/iphone.png');   background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;">
    <div class="overlay-right" style="color: white;font-weight: 600;margin-top: 94%;margin-left: 14px;">
  Test 1233
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought that adding the first line would help, but it doesnt. The two containers are still showing next to each others.
Is there a way to fix it with css only (ideally).

```
 .container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
  }

  .form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .log-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
  }


  .overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }


  .overlay {
    background: #44B5EB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #44B5EB, #0daaf5);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #44B5EB, #0daaf5);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
  }

  .overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .myClass {
    background: image-url('Admiralty.png');
  }
```

I have just added the styling that I am currently using.

Comment: What is your desired output/result ?

Comment: Code you are sharing is not enough to figure out what the problem is, you could share the css code as well along with the original size of the image

Comment: I currently have the form on one side and the image on the other side. When i switch to mobile, I would like the containter which contains the form to gow from width:50% to width 100% and take over the full screen hence, offsetting the image which was previously on the right .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found some sort of solution, not sure if it is the most elegant, but this is isL: I replace the straight:

```
  .log-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

with :

```
  /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
  @media only screen
  and (min-width : 1224px) {
    .log-in-container {
      left: 0;
      width: 50%;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }


  @media only screen
  and (max-width : 1224px) {
    .log-in-container {
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
```

So i adjust the width of the container based on the size of the screen, choosing 1224px as the threshold

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query. I would also suggest removing your inline styling as well as the `!important` property - This will override any other elements you style.